# Children's Book with Hooded Figures Wielding Pokers?

Tags: story-identification, books, illustrated-story

I'm trying to find a book that I read, or that I *think* I read, over 15 years ago so it would be from the 1990s or so. I remember it being more of a kids' book, English language, big painting-style or hand-drawn illustrations on some pages with the text either to one side or framing the pictures. The setting was some kind of medieval or pseudo-medieval Europe, or a fantasy version of it.

The one picture and/or characters I distinctly remember were these figures wearing hooded robes or cloaks and I swear that they were described as carrying red-hot pokers as weapons. They *might* have been some kind of enforcers or secret police for an evil monarch, because I think I remember them coming after children in the middle of the night if the children had done something wrong or as a way to terrorize orphans into behaving or as the simple reality that children would be taken away in the middle of the night. They sound a bit like the Ringwraiths but they definitely aren't.

I am positive that the children in the book were either orphans or runaways and the scene I can remember MIGHT have been part of a dream sequence but I recall that these hooded whoevers went into someone's house in the middle of the night, possibly an orphanage, with their pokers glowing and were described as going up a flight of stairs and along a hallway to find a particular character.

The book in question *might* have been a religious (Christian) fantasy book but I'm not sure. Does anyone know what I'm thinking of?

Comment: https://cdn1.spiegel.de/images/image-23701-860_poster_16x9-ekfe-23701.jpg

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Lol no, that's definitely not it.

Comment: @Valorum The trouble is that I can't think of any other details besides what I've put into the question, even with the edits I added. I read this book, if I really *did* read it, well over a decade ago and just the one time. It's been rattling around in my head for years and I've tried finding it but never had any luck.

Comment: It reminds me of "Little Orphant Annie", a poem with a lot of adaptions for children.Household help "Annie" tells the children of her employer stories, the first is how the goblins get a little boy from bed who do not say his prayers correctly... [poem on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Orphant_Annie)

Comment: @Allerleirauh Vaguely but I don't think that was it. I'm pretty sure that the hooded bad guys came after people who were a threat, not because they simply were naughty, a sort of Inquisition-cum-Ringwraith group.